# Consumer - Producer, assertion failure

Tags: c, multithreading, ubuntu

I have the bounded buffer, producer consumer problem to deal with and can only modify the prod and cons functions. This code runs without issues with only one consumer and producer threads. But with multiple of each it always gives me the same problem, sooner or later:

```
 p5p1: p5p2a.c:207: bb_remove: Assertion `bbp->cnt > 0' failed.
```

What I don't get is how can this error occur when I check the `bbp->cnt` variable before calling the `bbp_remove()` function.

**EDIT:** The problem has been solved. I was not checking the variable within the lock, in either of the functions.

```
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEBUG 0

#define BUF_SIZE    100000
#define ITER        10000000

#define PROD_THRD   3
#define CONS_THRD   3

#define USAGE_STRING    "Usage: %s\n"

extern int errno;

/* This is the bounded buffer type */
typedef struct {
    int cnt, in, out;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;       /* Mutex to avoid race conditions */
    int buf[BUF_SIZE];      /* The data passed is the id of the
             *  producer */
} bbuf_t;

typedef struct {
    bbuf_t *bbp;
    int      id;
} parg_t;

/* 
 * yield()
 * Because there is no yield system call in Linux, what we
 * do is to put the thread to sleep for 1 ms. Actually, it 
 * will sleep for at least 1/HZ, which is 10 ms in Linux/386.
 */
#define YIELD_s     0
#define YIELD_ns    1000000

void yield() {

    struct timespec st = {YIELD_s, YIELD_ns};

    if( (nanosleep(&st, NULL)) == -1 && (errno == EINVAL)) {
    perror("nanosleep");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
}

/* Initialize bounded buffer */
int bbuf_init(bbuf_t *bbp) {

    if(bbp == NULL)
    return 0;

    bbp->in = 0;
    bbp->out = 0;
    bbp->cnt = 0;
    pthread_mutex_init(&(bbp->lock), NULL); /* I do not understand, but the 
                     * compiler complains when I use
                     * PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER */
    return 1;
}

/* Print the bounded buffer members that matter */
void print_bbuf(bbuf_t *bbp) {
    printf("bbp->in = %d bbp->out = %d bbp_cnt = %d \n",
       bbp->in, bbp->out, bbp->cnt);
}

/* To validate the value of the members in, out and cnt of bbuf_t */
int val(int n, int min, int max) {
    return( (min <= n) && (n <= max));
}

/* Ensure that the values of the members in, out and cnt are consistent */
int consist(int cnt, int in, int out) {
    return ( in == ((out + cnt) % BUF_SIZE) );
}

/* This is the code of the checker thread. It is used to ensure that
 * the bounded buffer has not been corrupted.
 * Every 100 ms it checks the values of: in, out and cnt.
 * This thread exits either if it detects the buffer has been corrupted
 * or if it does not detect any activity in 50 consecutive iterations, 
 * i.e. approximately 5s. */

/* These constants are used with nanosleep() and
 *  put a process to sleep for 100 ms */

#define SLEEP_s     0
#define SLEEP_ns    100000000

#define MAX_IDLE    50

void *check(void *arg) {
    bbuf_t *bbp = arg;
    int cnt[2], in[2], out[2];      /* values read */
    int idle;
    struct timespec st = {SLEEP_s, SLEEP_ns}; /* 100 ms */

    while(1) {
    pthread_mutex_lock( &(bbp->lock) );
    in[1] = bbp->in;
    out[1] = bbp->out;
    cnt[1] = bbp->cnt;
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &(bbp->lock) );
    if(in[1] == in[0] && out[1] == out[0] && cnt[1] == cnt[0] ) {
        idle++;
        if( idle >= MAX_IDLE ) {
        printf("Checking thread exiting:");
        print_bbuf(bbp);
        printf("\t no activity detected for some time.\n");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
    } else {
        idle = 0;
    }
    if( !val(in[1], 0, BUF_SIZE - 1) ) {
        printf("Invalid value in = %d \n", in[1]);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    } else if ( !val(out[1], 0, BUF_SIZE - 1) ) {
        printf("Invalid value out = %d \n", out[1]);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    } else if ( !val(cnt[1], 0, BUF_SIZE) ) {
        printf("Invalid value cnt = %d \n", cnt[1]);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    } else if ( !consist(cnt[1], in[1], out[1]) ) {
        printf("Inconsistent buffer: cnt = %d in = %d out = %d \n",
           cnt[1], in[1], out[1]);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    if( (nanosleep(&st, NULL) == -1) && (errno == EINVAL)) {
        perror("nanosleep");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    in[0] = in[1];
    out[0] = out[1];
    cnt[0] = cnt[1];
    }
}    

/* The producer threads may use this code to
 *  enter one item into the buffer */

void bb_enter(bbuf_t *bbp, int me) {

    assert( bbp->cnt < BUF_SIZE);

    (bbp->buf)[bbp->in] = me;
    (bbp->in)++;
    (bbp->in) %= BUF_SIZE;
    (bbp->cnt)++;
    //printf("%d\n",bbp->cnt);
}

/* This is the code for the producer threads.
 *
  * To avoid busy waiting (or at least too much busy waiting) the producers
 * should yield, using the yield() defined above, if the buffer is
 * full. In that case, they should print a debugging message as well.
 *
 * Each producer should produce ITER (10 M) items: an integer with
 *  the id it receives in prod()'s argument.
 */
void *prod(void *arg) {
    parg_t *parg = (parg_t *)arg;
    bbuf_t *bbp = parg->bbp;
    int me = parg->id;

    /* Add variables and code, if necessary */
    printf("I am a producer and have started\n");
    int gcnt = 0;

    while( gcnt <= ITER ){
      if(bbp->cnt < BUF_SIZE){
          pthread_mutex_lock(&(bbp->lock));
          bb_enter(bbp,me);
          gcnt++;
          pthread_mutex_unlock(&(bbp->lock));}
      else if( bbp->cnt == (BUF_SIZE-1)) {printf("I shall produce yield()\n"); yield();}
    }

    printf("I am a producer and have ended\n");

    return;

}

/* The consumer threads may use this function to
 *  remove an item */

int bb_remove(bbuf_t *bbp) {
    int val;

    assert(bbp->cnt > 0);

    val = (bbp->buf)[bbp->out];
    (bbp->out)++;
    (bbp->out) %= BUF_SIZE;
    (bbp->cnt)--;
    return val;
}

/* This is the code for the consumer threads.
 * To avoid busy waiting (or at least too much busy waiting) consumers
 * should yield, using the yield() defined above, if the buffer is
 * empty. In that case, they should print a debugging message as well.
 *
 * Each consumer should consume ITER (10 M) items, and keep track of the 
 * producers of the items it consumes: use the cnt[] below.
 */
void *cons(void *arg) {
    bbuf_t *bbp = (bbuf_t *)arg;
    int cnt[PROD_THRD];

    /* Add variables and code, if necessary:
     *          do not forget to initialize cnt */

    printf("I am a consumer and have started\n");
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < PROD_THRD; i++){
    cnt[i] = 0;}

    int temp;
    int gcnt = 0;

    while( gcnt <= ITER ){
      if(bbp->cnt > 0){
         pthread_mutex_lock(&(bbp->lock));
         temp = bb_remove(bbp);
         gcnt++;
         cnt[temp]++;
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&(bbp->lock));}
      else if( bbp->cnt == 0) {printf("I shall consume yield()\n"); yield();}
    }
   printf("I am a consumer and have ended\n");
   return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i;
    pthread_t *tid, ctid;
    parg_t *parg;
    bbuf_t *bbp;


    /* This is to measure the time it takes to run the program */
    struct tms t;
    clock_t start, end;
    long ticks = sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);

    start = times(&t);

    if( argc != 1 ) {
        printf(USAGE_STRING, argv[0]);
    exit(1);
    }

    /* Array for pthread_join() */
    if((tid = (pthread_t *) malloc((PROD_THRD + CONS_THRD) * sizeof(pthread_t)))
       == NULL ) {
    printf("Out of memory.\n");
    exit(2);
    }

    /* Allocate Bounded Buffer */
    if((bbp = (bbuf_t *) malloc(sizeof(bbuf_t))) == NULL ) {
    printf("Out of memory. \n");
    exit(2);
    }

    /* Initialize Bounded Buffer */
    if( bbuf_init(bbp) == 0 ) {
    printf("Failed to initialize bounded buffer\n");
    exit(3);
    }

    /* Arguments for producer threads */
    if((parg = (parg_t *) malloc( PROD_THRD * sizeof (parg_t))) == NULL ) {
        printf("Out of memory.\n");
    exit(2);
    } 

    /* Create checker thread */
    if( pthread_create(&ctid, NULL, check, bbp) )
    perror("pthread_create");
    printf("Created checker thread %u\n", (unsigned)ctid);


    /* Create consumer threads */
    for( i = 0; i < CONS_THRD; i++ ) {
    /* We pass the same data structure, the bounded buffer,
     * to each consumer: they need to synchronize to access it */
    if( pthread_create(tid+i, NULL, cons, bbp) )
        perror("pthread_create");
    printf("Created consumer thread %u\n", (unsigned)tid[i]);
    }

    /* Create producer threads */
    for( i = 0; i < PROD_THRD; i++ ) {
    /* Because we want each consumer to keep track of the
     * producer of the items it consumes, we assign an
     * id to each producer thread */
    parg[i].bbp = bbp;
    parg[i].id = i;
    if( pthread_create(tid+(i+CONS_THRD), NULL, prod, parg+i) )
        perror("pthread_create");
    printf("Created producer thread %u (%d)\n", (unsigned)tid[i+CONS_THRD], i);
    }

    /* Join consumer and producer threads */
   for( i = 0; i < CONS_THRD + PROD_THRD; i ++ ) {
    if( pthread_join(tid[i], NULL) == 0 ) {
        printf("Joined thread %u.\n", (unsigned)tid[i]);
    } else {
        printf("Failed to join thread %u\n", (unsigned)tid[i]);
    }
    }

    /* Join checker thread */
    if( pthread_join(ctid, NULL) == 0 ) {
        printf("Joined checker thread %u.\n", (unsigned)ctid);
    } else {
    printf("Failed to join checker thread %u\n", (unsigned)ctid);
    }

    /* How long did it take to run this ? */
     end = times(&t);

    printf("Wall time %2.4f s \n", (float)(end - start) / ticks);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: I haven't looked at all the code, but you're not holding the lock when checking the count.

Answer (score 0):

You should enter the mutex lock before you check `bbp->cnt`.  Since you are checking it before you enter the mutex, another thread can reduce the value before you acquire the mutex and try to reduce the value yourself.